# Android data file location in phone

Tags: android

Where is the android data folder exists ?since i have to save large files and users should not able to see them ,i think to use data folder.But i don't know where is located in android phone.does it is on sdcard or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Internal storage`

`Internal storage` is best when you want to be sure that neither the user nor other apps can access your files.

Sample code:

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
String filename = "myfile";
String string = "Hello world!";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
  outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
  outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

public File getTempFile(Context context, String url) {
    File file;
    try {
        String fileName = Uri.parse(url).getLastPathSegment();
        file = File.createTempFile(fileName, null, context.getCacheDir());
    catch (IOException e) {
        // Error while creating file
    }
    return file;
}
```

For more details, please refer [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage).

Comment: what is mean by internal storage?sdcard or ram?

Comment: Please realize that internal storage offers only trivial security.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below to get the path of of data directory

```
    File f = Environment.getDataDirectory();

    System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```